# Implementing FHIR on Mirth Connect

Tags: mirth

I am using mirth connect version 3.9.1 , and i have a requirement to use fhir messages.

My question is how to send the json object(Has Bundle) to the Channel (FHIR Sender And FHIR Listener) and get the response ?

note that the Example FHIR Lsitener.xml Does not work for me and doesn't cover my use case.

Thanks